# Change shell from bash to ksh permanently with no admin rights

Tags: linux, bash, ksh, non-root-user

I need to change my PuTTY shell from `bash` to `ksh` permanently. The `chsh` command and editing `/etc/passwd` are not available to me as I don't have admin rights.

Please help me understand what needs to be changed in the `.profile` file or if it's something I need to change in the `.bashrc`/`.kshrc` files so I can use `ksh` moving forward.

Comment: Have you spoken to local administrators? There may be some local command that you need to use on your specific system, typically if a directory service is in use.

Comment: @Kusalananda support has recommended adding the 'exec ksh' command line at the end of the .profile file which has not worked for me - shell is still using bash interpreter...

Comment: Do you have a `~/.bash_profile` file? The `bash` shell will use that _instead of_ `~/.profile`, if it exists.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, I have a .bash_profile, .profile, and a .kshrc file.

Comment: In that case, add the `exec ksh` to the `.bash_profile` file.

Comment: You don't need root privs to run `chsh`.  A normal user can use it to change their shell to any shell listed in `/etc/shells`.  If it's not listed, well, you'll have to `exec ksh` from your `~/.bash_profile` as in Kusalananda's answer , or ask one of the admins to add `ksh` to `/etc/shells`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(According to comments...) Your administrator has told you to add `exec ksh` to your `~/.profile`  file, but that doesn't seem to be working for you.  It doesn't work because your `bash` login shell will use `~/.bash_profile` in place of `~/.profile` if the former exists.

Therefore, add `exec ksh` to your `~/.bash_profile` file instead.

Personally, I would use something like the following (assuming the `ksh` shell executable is known to be located at `/bin/ksh`):

```bsh
if [ -x /bin/ksh ]; then
    export SHELL=/bin/ksh
    exec "$SHELL" -l
fi
```

This would be the whole of my `~/.bash_profile` file, and it would start `/bin/ksh` as a login shell if `/bin/ksh` existed and was executable.
The `ksh` shell would then proceed to replace the `bash` shell and read your `~/.profile` file etc. (so *remove* `exec ksh` from `~/.profile` if you have added it there).  Your `~/.bashrc` file would no longer be used at all.

The above code will leave you with a `bash` shell if, for some reason, the `ksh` shell is removed from your system.

Comment: Currently this is the code in my .bashrc file: if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then . /etc/bashrc fi. Should I comment this all out and add your code?

Comment: I implemented your solution, it seems to be working after logging in and out, it is now using ksh interprator. But when I echo $SHELL, it's still showing bin/bash. Do you know why?

Comment: @st789 What is in your `~/.bashrc` file is irrelevant. It is not used. Your `SHELL` variable will always show your true login shell, which is `bash`. There is nothing stopping you from setting this to some other value, for example `/bin/ksh`, before starting your `ksh` shell. I'll make a small update to my answer with that in mind.

Comment: thank you this has resolved my issue!

Comment: what does the "-x" flag do in this case? also the "-l" flag? Is this if statement essentially checking if /bin/ksh director exists then to run it as shell interpreter?

Comment: @st789 The `-x` test is a test for whether the given file is (accessible and) executable. This is documented in ith `test` manual. We don't want to try to run a shell that may not exist.  The `-l` option for `ksh` starts the shell as a login shell. This is documented in the `ksh` manual.  The `~/.bash_profile` file is executed by your `bash` login shell, so we start a `ksh` login shell.

Comment: so with this solution you provided, is my shell initially starting in bash and switching to ksh, or is it starting from ksh from the beginning? i noticed when i log into the server the initial prompt "root.....etc....etc" is printing twice.

Comment: @st789 Your real login shell is `bash`. It reads `~/.bash_profile`, because that is what `bash` does when it is started as a login shell.  This file replaces the shell with a `ksh` login shell.  This shell starts up by reading `~/.profile`.  So `bash` starts, and executes `ksh`.